# Erdős–Sierpiński duality in locally compact Polish groups (e.g. $\mathbb{R}^n$)

Tags: set-theory, real-analysis, lo.logic, descriptive-set-theory

Erdős–Sierpiński mapping for a locally compact Polish group $G$ is a bijection $f$ from $G$ to $G$ such that $A$ is a null set in $G$ with respect to the Haar measure if and only if $f(A)$ is a meager set in $G$.

Erdős and Sierpiński proved that assuming CH, such a mapping exists for $G=\mathbb{R}$ and it is well-known that it also holds for $G=2^\omega$.
**However, what about for general locally compact Polish group $G$?** (For instance, $\mathbb{R}^n$.)

According to the following paper, for any Polish group, there is no such mapping that also preserves the group addition. This fact was known previously for $G=\mathbb{R}$ and $G=2^\omega$.

*Balka, Richárd, Duality between measure and category in uncountable locally compact abelian Polish groups. Real Anal. Exchange36(2010/11/2011), no.2, 245–256.*

Comment: The Erdős-Sierpiński mapping does not exist for a general locally compact Polish group $G$. It is impossible to find a bijection preserving Haar null sets and meager sets while also maintaining the group structure. This limitation extends beyond specific cases like $\mathbb{R}$ or $2^\omega$.

Comment: I understand that addition preserving Erdős-Sierpiński mapping does not exist for general locally compact Polish group $G$. The question is, is there a Erdős-Sierpiński mapping for general locally compact Polish group $G$, that does not preserve addition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, assuming $\mathsf{CH}$ there is a bijection $f\colon X\to X$ such that $f=f^{-1}$ and $f(N)$ is meager iff $N$ is null with respect to the Haar measure whenever $X$ is a locally compact Polish group (but as you mentioned in the question there are no such bijections respecting the addition).

Let $X=\Bbb R$ and $\mu$ be the Lebesgue measure. The construction of the Erdős–Sierpiński mapping $f\colon\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$, as presented in Theorem 19.5 and 19.6 of Oxtoby's *Measure and category* uses the following properties of $X$ and $\mu$ under $\mathsf{CH}$:

1. If $N\subseteq X$ is a null set, then there is a null set with cardinality $\mathfrak c=\aleph_1$ in $X\setminus N$;
2. If $M\subseteq X$ is a meager set, then there is a meager set with cardinality $\mathfrak c=\aleph_1$ in $X\setminus M$;
3. Every meager subset of $X$ is contained in an $F_\sigma$ meager subset of $X$ and there are $\aleph_1$ many $F_\sigma$ subsets of $X$;
4. Every null subset of $X$ is contained in a $G_\delta$ null subset of $X$ and there are $\aleph_1$ many $G_\delta$ subsets of $X$;
5. $X$ can be written as the union of an $F_\sigma$ meager set and a $G_\delta$ null set.

I claim that properties 1-5 hold whenever $X$ is an uncountable locally compact Polish space and $\mu$ a nonatomic Radon measure on $X$, in particular whenever $X$ is a locally compact Polish group and $\mu$ its Haar measure, so that the same construction gives an Erdős–Sierpiński mapping for $X$.

Indeed suppose $X$ is uncountable locally compact Polish and $\mu$ is a Radon measure on $X$. Properties 2 and 3 are basic facts about Polish spaces. For property 1 suppose $N\subseteq X$ is $\mu$-null. Then by inner regularity $X\setminus N$ contains a closed uncountable set $F$. If $\mu(F)=0$ we are done, otherwise (using nonatomicity of $\mu$ again) we can build a Cantor scheme $(F_s)_{s\in 2^{<\omega}}$ in $F$ with $\mu(F_s)<2^{-|s|}$, so that the resulting Cantor set is an uncountable null set. Property 4 is immediate from the outer regularity of $\mu$. Property 5 can be shown as in $\Bbb R$, enumerate a countable dense subset $(x_i)_{i<\omega}$ and, using nonatomicity of $\mu$, local compactness of $X$ and finiteness of $\mu$ on compact sets, find for each $n,j\in\omega$, a neighbourhood $B_{n,j}$ of $x_j$ with $\mu(B_{n,j})<2^{-n-j}$. Then $A=\bigcap_n\bigcap_j B_{n,j}$ is a null $G_\delta$ set whose complement is meager.

Answer (score -2):

Based on your above [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/461406/erd%c5%91s-sierpi%c5%84ski-duality-in-locally-compact-polish-groups-e-g-mathbbrn#comment1196762_461406), consider the general locally compact Polish group $G = \mathbb{R}^n$ equipped with the usual topology and addition as its group operation. Let's define a mapping $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ as follows:
$f(x) = \begin{cases} 
      x & \text{if } x \text{ is rational} \\
      x + c & \text{if } x \text{ is irrational} 
   \end{cases}$
where $c$ is a fixed irrational vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

This mapping $f$ acts as a bijection on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and satisfies the Erdős-Sierpiński properties concerning Haar null sets and meager sets. However, it does not preserve the addition operation since $f(x + y) \neq f(x) + f(y)$ for most pairs of vectors $x$ and $y$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: $f$ is not a bijection - $f(0)=f(-c)$, and $c$ is not in the image of $f$. It also doesn't have the Erdos-Sierpinski property - $f(A)$ differs from $A+c$ by a countable set, so is null (resp. meager) iff $A$ is, and there are sets which are null but not meager and vice versa.

Comment: @Wojowu You're right; my  construction doesn't satisfy the necessary properties for the Erdős-Sierpiński mapping,am going to edit my answer giving another example

Comment: If the edited answer is not forthcoming, perhaps this answer needs to be deleted